# Fast way to convert strings into lists of ints in a Pandas column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to compute the Hamming distance between all strings in a column in a large dataframe. I have over 100,000 rows in this column so with all pairwise combinations, which is 10x10^9 comparisons. These strings are short DNA sequences. I would like to quickly convert every string in the column to a list of integers, where a unique integer represent each character in the string. E.g.

```
"ACGTACA" -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

then I use `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` to quickly and efficiently compute the hamming distance between all of these. Is there a fast way to do this in Pandas?

I have tried using `apply` but it is pretty slow:

```
mapping = {"A":0, "C":1, "G":2, "T":3}
df.apply(lambda x: np.array([mapping[char] for char in x]))
```

`get_dummies` and other Categorical operations don't apply because they operate on a per row level. Not within the row.

Comment: `pretty slow` needs some dummy data and a benchmarking :)

Comment: can u show ur, dataframe?

Comment: The Hamming distance is based on equality or inequality of the elements, so a translation of ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'] to [0, 1, 2 ,3] should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Hamming distance doesn't care about magnitude differences, I can get about a 40-60% speedup just replacing `df.apply(lambda x: np.array([mapping[char] for char in x]))` with `df.apply(lambda x: map(ord, x))` on made-up datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test the performance of this, but you could also try somthing like

```
atest = "ACGTACA"
alist = atest.replace('A', '3.').replace('C', '2.').replace('G', '1.').replace('T', '0.').split('.')
anumlist = [int(x) for x in alist if x.isdigit()]
```

results in:

```
[3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3]
```

Edit: Ok, so testing it with atest = "ACTACA"*100000 takes a while :/
Maybe not the best idea...

Edit 5:
Another improvement:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mapping = {'A' : 0, 'C' : 1, 'G' : 2, 'T' : 3}

    def char2num(self, astring):
        return [self.mapping[c] for c in astring]

def main():
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        atest = "AGTCAGTCATG"*10000000
        t = Test()
        alist = t.char2num(atest)
        testme = np.array(alist)
        print testme, len(testme)
        print datetime.datetime.now() - now    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Takes about 16 seconds for 110.000.000 characters and keeps your processor busy instead of your ram:

```
[0 2 3 ..., 0 3 2] 110000000
0:00:16.866659
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your test data

```
In [39]: pd.options.display.max_rows=12

In [40]: N = 100000

In [41]: chars = np.array(list('ABCDEF'))

In [42]: s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(chars, size=4 * np.prod(N)).view('S4'))

In [45]: s
Out[45]: 
0        BEBC
1        BEEC
2        FEFA
3        BBDA
4        CCBB
5        CABE
         ... 
99994    EEBC
99995    FFBD
99996    ACFB
99997    FDBE
99998    BDAB
99999    CCFD
dtype: object
```

These don't actually have to be the same length the way we are doing it.

```
In [43]: maxlen = s.str.len().max()

In [44]: result = pd.concat([ s.str[i].astype('category',categories=chars).cat.codes for i in range(maxlen) ], axis=1)

In [47]: result
Out[47]: 
       0  1  2  3
0      1  4  1  2
1      1  4  4  2
2      5  4  5  0
3      1  1  3  0
4      2  2  1  1
5      2  0  1  4
...   .. .. .. ..
99994  4  4  1  2
99995  5  5  1  3
99996  0  2  5  1
99997  5  3  1  4
99998  1  3  0  1
99999  2  2  5  3

[100000 rows x 4 columns]
```

So you get a factorization according the same categories (e.g. the codes are meaningful)

And pretty fast

```
In [46]: %timeit pd.concat([ s.str[i].astype('category',categories=chars).cat.codes for i in range(maxlen) ], axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be much difference between using `ord` or a dictionary-based lookup that exactly maps A->0, C->1 etc:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bases = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']

rowlen = 4
nrows = 1000000

dna = pd.Series(np.random.choice(bases, nrows * rowlen).view('S%i' % rowlen))

lookup = dict(zip(bases, range(4)))

%timeit dna.apply(lambda row: map(lookup.get, row))
# 1 loops, best of 3: 785 ms per loop

%timeit dna.apply(lambda row: map(ord, row))
# 1 loops, best of 3: 713 ms per loop
```

Jeff's solution is also not far off in terms of performance:

```
%timeit pd.concat([dna.str[i].astype('category', categories=bases).cat.codes for i in range(rowlen)], axis=1)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop
```

A major advantage of this approach over mapping the rows to lists of ints is that the categories can then be viewed as a single `(nrows, rowlen)` uint8 array via the `.values` attribute, which could then be passed directly to `pdist`.